# Layout in Emulator is not matching that from Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

So I'm completely new to Android Development and I'm working through a book on Android Game Development. First game we build is called Tappy Defender.

Anyway, they provide me with background image and told me to put a button and a TextView. I put the background in the drawable folder and assigned it to the background for the Activity, I also aligned both the TextView and the button.

However, when I build and run the program in the emulator, both the button and the TextView are located in the top left corner (in landscape) and are overlapping each other. The background also doesn't show at all.

I'm so confused as to what it is that I'm doing wrong as I followed the steps correctly and have gone over it several times.

Any help appreciated.

I've included the .xml file too:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible"
    tools:background="@drawable/background"
    tools:context="com.example.tappydefender.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonPlay"
        android:layout_width="122dp"
        android:layout_height="39dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Play"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="293dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="280dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textHighScore"
        android:layout_width="158dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="264dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="258dp"
        tools:text="High Score: 99999" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a Constraint layout, but you are not constraining anything. Furthermore, you are using "tools" attributes, which only apply to the emulator, and are ignored when the app is built.

You need to set constraints to your views, like

```
app:layout_constrainTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/otherView"
```

Please read on Constraint layout (https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html) and apply constraints to your views.

Comment: Yeah, I just found this out myself, was about to come and edit. I have the TextView and Button in the correct place now, but still no background image.

Comment: never mind, changed the `tools` to `android` and we working with gas now, thanks!